# convert JSON Object to Java bean

Tags: json, jsonserializer

How can i convert a json objet to java bean(MainBean) of following type

```
class MainBean{
private int id;
private SubBean sBean;
}  
class SubBean{
private String name;
private List<DBean> dBean;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are alot of libraries that can do it.
For exanple, you can do it using `Google-Gson`

```
MainBean bean = new Gson().fromJson(yourJsonAsString, MainBean.class);
```

JSON like this will be converted well

```
{"id" : 1, "sBean" : {"name" : "beanname", "dBean" : []}}
```